# uninitialized constant Rails::Command::Actions::APP_PATH (NameError) when trying to start Rails engine server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

The full error is

```
~/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.5/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:8:in `set_application_directory!': uninitialized constant Rails::Command::Actions::APP_PATH (NameError)
```

I recently upgrade from Rails 4.x to 5.x.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to generate (or regenerate) "binstubs" for the dummy application.

```
cd spec/dummy
bundle exec rails app:update:bin
```

You should now be able to start the dummy application, from the `spec/dummy` directory, as such:

```
bundle exec bin/rails server
```

The `spec/dummy/script` directory can also be deleted.