# Error: uninitialized constant Rails::Command::Server Command::APP_PATH (NameError) on starting rails server - rails 5.2.2

Tags: ruby

I have installed rails 5.2.2. On server start(rails s), I am getting following exception,

```
'block in perform':uninitialized constant Rails::Command::Server Command::APP_PATH (NameError)
```

I tried bundle install and also downgrading rails server and relevant ruby version. But it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Please anyone help me ...Thanks in advance

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/49627511/10522579

Comment: @ray.. Thank you..I tried it.But still getting the same error :(